# npm webdriver-manager latest version does not work for chrome 115 and above where chrome browser for testing needs to get downloaded

Tags: behat, npm-package, webdriver-manager

npm webdriver-manager latest version does not work for chrome 115 and above where chrome browser for testing needs to get downloaded. This is used for Behat end to end testing

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-manager

Is there a way that we can download the chrome browser for testing and work with new chrome versions

Tried to check if any other alternate solution is available to use to work with